# mysql how to use LIMIT with SELECT SUM CHAR_LENGTH

Tags: mysql

I have a column with simple words (only one word for each row)
I need to extract from this column not more than 10,000 characters aprox. (9000 to be more safe) each time.

So I need **one query to extract from 0 to 9000 characters**

The **next query to extract from 9000 to 18000 characters** and so on...

I saw some like this but is for entire table

```
SELECT SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(my_column)) FROM my_table;
```

Can achieve that in MySQL ?

Comment: Is there a primary key (or other unique index) on this table and does the order matter?

Comment: in principle the order does not matter (only need to no repeat same row in the next query). But the table has a id as primary key and the word column have a UNIQUE index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want this broken down by words, not just literally blocks of characters. If all you wanted was blocks of characters (no concern for word boundaries) and your table was small enough, you could probably just do something like

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; -- Need this to be much larger than default
SELECT substr(group_concat(my_column), 9000, 9000)
FROM my table
```

Assuming you do care about column boundaries, my first thought is that you could break it down by the total count of characters until that point:

```
SELECT my_column
FROM
(
 SELECT my_column, ((SELECT SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(my_column)) FROM my_table mt2 WHERE mt2.my_key <= mt1.my_key)) as endidx
 FROM my_table mt1
) mt
WHERE endidx > 9000 and endidx <= 9000 + 9000
```

[Here's an SQL Fiddle to play around with that query a bit](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d03c/36/0).

I'm not confident this would scale well, but I think something like this works in principle. Note that there is a huge assumption here that your increment (9000) is larger than the largest possible word. If that's not true, you'd have to modify this. You also might need to tweak it a bit depending on how you want boundary conditions handled, but maybe it's a starting point for what you need.

Comment: Congratulations for your great job and thank you for your time. But unfortunately for large amount of data that not work. I have tried it first with one small table (like in your fiddle to be sure that mi server is ok and work as expected)  but when I have tried it with one real table 25-30000 words ... with `WHERE endidx > 2 and endidx <= 2 + 2` after one hour of process have not yet finish (and have stopped it). However I mark your answer as  accepted if someone need some like this for smaller amount of data. Sorry for mi english

Comment: I feared it wouldn't scale well, but unfortunately I am not sure of a better way of doing it. Depending how (and how frequently) you are inserting the data, maybe you could actually add a column to your table equivalent to endidx (i.e. calculate the character count of previous rows during inserts so that the selects are fast).